# Incorrect class displayed when using 'apply' function in R

Tags: r

I see a problem with the apply function in R.
   1. This does not show the right class.

```
 apply(iris,2,function(x) class(x))
 #  Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
 # "character"  "character"  "character"  "character"  "character"
```

2. This shows the right class.

   ```
   apply(iris[,1:4],2,function(x) class(x))
   #  Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
   #  "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"
   ```

Can anyone show me how to get the class for all columns?

Answer (score 0):

`apply` coerces the first argument (i.e., `iris` or `iris[1:4]` in your case) into a matrix. Matrices can only have one class. In (2) above, columns 1 - 4 are numeric so you get a numeric matrix. In (1) however, column 5 contains strings, forcing the entire matrix to be a character matrix.

Vectors work the same way and the following code might be instructive:

```
> class(c(1, 2))
[1] "numeric"
> class(c(1, "two"))
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Thank you @Buckminster. I found that I can use 'sapply' to display the right classes: `sapply(iris,function(x) class(x))`

Comment: The reason is that `sapply` treats your data.frame as a list rather than coercing it to a matrix. Also, the anonymous function call is unnecessary--`sapply(iris, class)` produces the same results.